# Web-Crawling with playwright in Python

Tags: python, web-crawler, playwright

Good day, everyone.

I have an assignment on the condition that I should use crawling_{201904307} in def part like the image.

However, it says there is an error (invalid syntax), supposed to be from using {} in def.

Please help me out of this problem.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Python code with syntax error]

It was expected not to have any errors for crawling.

Comment: That's not a valid function name. There's no if or but. Perhaps the assignment asks for something else?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`crawling_{201904307}` is not a valid name for a function name in python. Method names can only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores.